# Can I sub-query for EmailTemplates from Folder?

Tags: soql, email-template

In a trigger, I want to query all the EmailTemplates in a given folder into a Map, but don't want to hard-code the FolderID. I'm trying to do it with a subquery, but I think the polymorphic child relationship may prevent that.

I've tried:

```
SELECT DeveloperName, Id 
      (SELECT DeveloperName, Id FROM EmailTemplate.FolderId)
FROM Folder WHERE DeveloperName = 'Resident_Requests' AND Type = 'Email'
```

`EmailTemplate.FolderId` is what Workbench shows as the Child Relationship name, but I've also tried `EmailTemplate` and `EmailTemplates` with no joy.

Does this relationship require me to first query Folder for the Id and then EmailTemplate for the templates, based on the FolderId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship name is not specified so we can't subquery.

[image: RealForceExplorer snapshot of relationships under Folder object]

The `EmailTemplate.FolderId` describes going "up" (on EmailTemplate there is such field) but the part about going "down" is blank. Compare with `SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact` vs. `SELECT Id (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account`.

You could achieve it by querying for all EmailTemplates and then bucketing them in a `Map<Id, List<EmailTemplate>>` manually:

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, FolderId, Folder.DeveloperName
FROM EmailTemplate
ORDER BY FolderId, DeveloperName
```

Remember that some folder ids reported that way will be fake (your personal email templates will show your user id, unfiled public templates will show your org's id) and might need filtering out in WHERE.